# Keeping email format through out database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, email

So say I'm sending an email to someone. I can highlight the text in my email client, then I can make it bold for example. Now what I'm doing is having a user send an email to the email I give them, and I insert it into my database. Then say I want to echo it on a page. The bold will be gone, sadly. So my question is how can I retain this? Is there any plugin or some sort of code I can use? I've tried a bunch of research, but nothing on the topic yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you receive or send an e-mail message with formatting, it most likely consists of 2 parts: A plain text part and an html part.

Instead of saving the text part, you should save the html part (or both...). That way you can reproduce the e-mail with the formatting without any problems in any viewer that supports html (e-mail clients, web-browsers, etc.).

Comment: Great answer, and it kind of solved my problem. Well since I'll be displaying it to users, what about XSS? Wouldn't the user sending the email be able to inject the code, and if I use `htmlspecialchars()` it'll strip all the formatting?

Comment: @user302975 That could be a problem, if you want to retain the html you open yourself to xss and when you protect yourself from that, you will show html tags instead of a marked-up message. You would have to look for a way to clean / validate your messages.

Comment: Sound fair. Know any ways I can block certain tags? Should I just query the row to see if it contains some tag other than the ones I want, then get rid of it if it does?

Comment: @user302975 No, that's pointless as you can add javascript to any tag (event handlers is a common example). You'd better look for a proven solution / library that helps with that.

Comment: if the input came from WYSIWYG u can use htmlentities(strip_tags($text, "<a><b><i><h1></h2>"));

only allow all html tags that you allow WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 0):

Create a set of tags that indicate BOLD sentence i.e  < b > < / b > tags like they do right here on stack overflow.

Comment: So there's no easier way? Instead of essentially having the user learn a new set of tags?

Comment: Not what I am saying. Figure out what identifies a bold sentence or what have you. Then sort the tags yourself in your database